# What is the memory layout of dynamic arrays?

Tags: d

```
auto  array =  new Foo[100];
```

My first question is how does this look internally? What I assume:

If Foo is a class, then array is a pointer to an array of pointer of foo objects `vector<Foo*> v //c++`

If Foo is a struct , then array is a pointer to an array of Foo objects. `vector<Foo> v //c++`

Is a dynamic array in D contiguous in memory like in C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A D dynamic array looks like this:

```
struct Array(T) {
     size_t length;
     T* ptr;
}
```

Doing `new T[size]` is basically running this:

```
Array!T array;
array.length = size;
array.ptr = GC.malloc(size * T.sizeof);
```

So, yes, the memory of the elements is contiguous like in C++. The rest of your question gets into the specifics of what T is, and you're right about what you thought:

If `Foo` is a class, that means any reference to `Foo` works like a pointer, so it is like `Foo*` array in C++ - `T.sizeof` when T is a class is always equal to `void*.sizeof`*, the objects work by reference. If it is a struct, it is all in-place, like `vector<Foo>` in C++.

Fun fact with structs btw: they aren't necessarily packed in the array due to alignment issues. Consider the following:

```
struct Foo {
   ushort s;
   uint i;
}
```

`Foo.sizeof` you might expect to be 6... but it is actually 8 because the uint will be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, causing two bytes of padding after `s`. If you add `align(1)` to the uint field, you'll override this, putting `i` right next to `s` in memory. However, since we're talking about arrays, you'll want to node that `Foo[]` elements would /still/ have its own alignment... `Foo.sizeof == 8` still so a `Foo[2]` has a size of 16. The inner `align(1)` just moved the padding to the end of the struct, it didn't remove it entirely for the cases of arrays.

If you want a `Foo[]` that is packed with no padding between elements, you'd also want to add `align(1)` to the *outside* of the struct: `align(1) struct Foo { /* ... */ }`. Then Foo.sizeof == 6 and there's no padding in the array.

- If you want to get the size of the object itself, for example if you're writing your own version of `new MyClass`, there's a way to do that too: `__traits(classInstanceSize, Foo)`. http://dlang.org/traits.html#classInstanceSize But D does classes by reference because it is easier to keep sanity in the presence of inheritance.

Anyway, I probably went into more detail than you actually wanted/needed but in short, you're right about what happens with `Foo` and a D dynamic array is laid out similarly to a C++ vector. Biggest difference between the two is a C++ vector can be copied with the assign operator, it is a value type. A D array will always just be sliced - the length and pointer (remember the first layout in this post) is copied, but the contents are not. You need to explicitly copy the data in D with `array.dup` or `foo[] = bar[]`.

Further reading:

- http://dlang.org/arrays.html ("Array Operations" is the `foo[] = bar[]` stuff, "Array Properties" has `dup`, and much more in there)
- http://dlang.org/abi.html (see the "Arrays" header - this describes the length/ptr layout)
- http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html (talks about the array itself vs the slice you manipulate and explains some internals about dynamic array memory management)
- http://dlang.org/struct.html (you can find info about the struct alignment stuff there)
- http://wiki.dlang.org/Books

Comment: but the custom `new` also passes in the required size (to account for subclasses)

Comment: Thanks that was actually a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

`array` itself is a struct with a `size_t length` and a `Foo* ptr`

This is described in http://dlang.org/abi.html (look for arrays)

And yes the storage is in contiguous memory.